# Proof $\mu \{ x \in \mathbb{R}: |f|>t \}, t \to \infty$ if $\int |f| < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I apologize if my notation is not 100% correct. I'm not even sure if this fact requires proof or is considered obvious.

If $f$ is integrable, i.e. $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f| < \infty$, does it follow that $\mu \{x \in \mathbb{R}:|f|>t \} \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$. Here's my proof:

For $t$, define sequence $t_0 < t_1 \ldots <t_n, n \to \infty$ and a sequence of disjoint intervals $I^{t_n}_j = [x_j, x_{j+1}]$ equipped with measure $\mu$ such that $f>t_n$ on each of these intervals. by countable additivity and monotonicity of $t_n$ (again, I'm not 100% sure of this step - is this enough or the inequality requires a deeper proof?),
$$
\mu (\cup_{j=1}^{\infty}I_j) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu(I^{t_{n}}_j) \geq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu(I^{t_{n+1}}_j)
$$
By integrability, if $\int |f|< \infty$, then $|f|<\infty$, and, since the sequence $t_n$ is infinite, $\exists \ n^{\ast}$ s.t. $t_{n^{\ast}} < f < t_{n^{\ast}+1}$ and $\mu(I^{t_{n}}_j)=0 \ \forall n>n^{\ast}+1$. Therefore,
$$
\lim_{n \to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu(I^{t_{n+1}}_j) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(I^{t_{n+1}}_j)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}0=0
$$
Hence $\mu \{|f|>t \} \to 0$.

Comment: Better to use $$t \cdot \chi_{\{ x \in \mathbb{R}: |f|>t \} } \leq |f|$$ and then integrate both sides for a fixed $t >0$ to conclude $$\mu \{ x \in \mathbb{R}: |f|>t \} \leq \frac{\int |f| \, d\mu}{t}$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring thanks, so the inequality implies convergence to $0$ on RHS as $t \to \infty$?

Comment: Yes.  This is one of the standard ways of proving that statement (and almost nothing is "obvious" to not require a proof).  A more precise statement can be made if you can use Fubini-Tonelli, but it would be overkill here.

Comment: Obvious just means it has been proved :-).

Comment: @BrianMoehring so my proof is not incorrect, but it's not direct, right?

Comment: @Alex : As one perspective, I cannot follow your proof. I do not know what the intervals $I_j^{t_n}=[x_j, x_{j+1}]$ mean.

Comment: The definition is in the same sentence ('...such that $f>t_n$ on these intervals') - is this not rigorous enough?